# TensorFlow and TFLite - loss of accuracy / runtime

Tags: tensorflow, runtime, tensorflow-lite

Is there a general statement if or how much the accuracy and runtime at the inference decrease when using a TFLite model (.tflite) instead the original TensorFlow model (.h5)?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. This really relies on how the model looks like along with what sort of optimization was applied on converting the H5 to tflite. But generally if you do not apply any sort of additional optimization but just performed the float32 conversion to tflite, I'd say most of the time tflite would generate the equivalent level of accuracy compared to the original model.